# How to remember the credentials for a folder share path

Tags: active-directory, windows-domain

When I log into my account (Domain) from PC1 and try to access a **shared** **folder** present in a **Non**-**domain** **PC**, I am prompted with a window to enter username and password.

[image: Prompt for Creds]

But when I log into my domain account from another PC, (PC2) and try to access the same shared folder, I am **not prompted** for credentials.

I actually do not want to be asked for folder share credentials every time after restart.
But I am puzzled why 2 PC’s connected to the same domain exhibit different behavior?

And what configuration/ settings can I compare between PC1 and PC2.

**Plus:**

Both the PCs are shutdown every day. No passwords are stored in the windows credential manager of both PCs

The folder share of non domain PC is not configured for anonymous access and will not be done.

Certain GPO policies like Network access: Do not allow storage of passwords and credentials for network authentication is not enabled currently and is managed by the Domain controller*

Comment: Are you using the same account on both systems? Are there any GPOs (either domain-wide or local) that would regulate NTLM usage?

Comment: Yes, I am using the same accounts on both the systems.  No GPO's are explicitly setup to regulate NTLM usage.